# Display product thumbnails on category/section page?

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm trying to display the thumbnail images of each product on category page in Stencil CLI - BigCommerce with the option to slide. The most logical thing to do was to take the snippet from product-view.html and just paste it in card.html, unfortunately, it was to easy to be true.

I've tried changing the handlebars multiple times and replacing the a href url, but still no luck.

```
    <ul class="productView-thumbnails"{{#gt product.images.length 5}} data-slick='{
            "infinite": false,
            "mobileFirst": true,
            "slidesToShow": 5,
            "slidesToScroll": 1
        }'{{/gt}}>
        {{#each product.images}}
            <li class="productView-thumbnail">
                <a
                    class="productView-thumbnail-link"
                    href="{{getImage this 'product_size' (cdn ../theme_settings.default_image_product)}}"
                    data-image-gallery-item
                    data-image-gallery-new-image-url="{{getImage this 'product_size' (cdn ../theme_settings.default_image_product)}}"
                    data-image-gallery-zoom-image-url="{{getImage this 'zoom_size' (cdn ../theme_settings.default_image_product)}}">
                    <img class="lazyload" data-sizes="auto" src="{{cdn 'img/loading.svg'}}" data-src="{{getImage this 'productview_thumb_size' (cdn ../theme_settings.default_image_product)}}" alt="{{this.alt}}" title="{{this.alt}}">
                </a>
            </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
```

Any ideas ? Thanks.

Comment: I'm developer myself, just new to Stencil CLI. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's not possible using handlebars helpers. according to documentation, product thumbnails is not assigned as global attributes. so it won't work if you copy the code to category template.